# Two part conditional statement not working inside karate.config

Tags: karate

I am trying to set up a conditional statement in the karate-config.js file, it is as follows:

```
karate.configure('afterScenario', function () { if (condition) karate.call(path@method); if (condition) karate.call(path@method) });
```

However, even when the second condition is being met, only the first condition is actually being run. Any ideas?

Comment: that doesn't make any sense to me so I pass on this question

Comment: @PeterThomas can I have two instances of Karate.configure lines inside karate-config.js each with an afterScenario/afterFeature call? I am finding that the second overrides the first if I do. In the scenario I highlighted in the question, I attempted to combine into a single afterScenario call and even then only the first IF statement is being kicked off even when both IF conditions are fulfilled in my scenarios.

Comment: I'm still lost, sorry. make it simpler if you can. as always, if you can make your example something I can cut and paste and run locally, I wouldn't ask all these questions. your move

Comment: Your example is not clear. Please put a more concrete example. Both if condition looks the same - if(condition) ..call. I am assuming you have just posted a generic example. In your case when second condition is TRUE is any part of First condition also true. EX:
# CONDITION 1 - IF( A OR B) Then do Something
# CONDITION 2 - IF( B OR C) then do something.

In case you code passing condition B = TRUE then code will always enter the CONDITION 1.